# Blank results from implicit Python library for recommendations

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I'm using the Python implicit library (https://github.com/benfred/implicit) hoping to generate some product recommendations for my user base. I have data of 13,000 product views from my user base. I've extracted this data into a csv that looks like the following:

```
user_id, 1, 2, 3
1, 0, 1, 0
2, 1, 1, 0
3, 0, 0, 1
```

My csv above has product_id's across the top and user_ids on the left hand side for the first column in the row. The 1 or 0 for each user reflect if the user has viewed that product_id. Below is the code I have so far for trying to generate recommendations:

```
import implicit
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sparse

data = pd.read_csv('data/interactions_matrix.csv')
interactions = sparse.csr_matrix(data.to_sparse().to_coo())

# initialize a model
model = implicit.als.AlternatingLeastSquares()

# train the model on a sparse matrix of item/user/confidence weights
model.fit(interactions)

user_ids = [1,2,3]

# recommend items for a user
for user_id in user_ids:
    print(user_id)
    print(model.recommend(user_id, interactions))
```

Unfortunately when I run the results I am just getting a bunch of blank arrays, which makes me think I am doing something clearly wrong. I'm guessing it's the format of the data I am importing but I am having a hard time finding information on example data formats to read into the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading up the data like that, your interactions matrix still has an entry for every item/user pair - which for this library indicates that every user has liked every item. The recommend call by default removes already liked items (with the filter_already_liked_items parameter), causing the results to be empty arrays like you saw - but this also means that the model you trained won't be any good either.

You should call `interactions.eliminate_zeros()` to remove the zero entries before fitting the model. Also rather than have a dense matrix in CSV format and convert to a coo, it's probably easier just to list out triples of itemid/userid/value

Comment: thanks! I was able to generate some results after making these changes, one thing Im running into when running the above is an "IndexError: index (1121) out of range" when iterating through my user_ids, are these supposed to be indexes and not the actual user id? also the result returned (17, 0.038822174), is this the index of the product or product id?